# Parallel excel sheet read from dask

Tags: python-2.7, dask

> Hello All the examples that I came across for using dask thus far has
>   been multiple csv files in a folder being read using dask read_csv
>   call.
>
> if I am provided an xlsx file with multiple tabs, can I use anything
>   in dask to read them parallely?

P.S. I am using pandas 0.19.2 with python 2.7

Comment: You would be best to write a function to read one tab (taking the tab ID as input), and look into dask's `delayed` function. Are you wanting to process all the tabs as a single data-frame?

Comment: This notebook may be of interest: https://gist.github.com/mrocklin/e7b7b3a65f2835cda813096332ec73ca

Answer (score 5):

For those using Python 3.6:

```
#reading the file using dask
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed

parts = dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(excel_file, sheet_name=0, usecols = [1, 2, 7])
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)

print(df.head())
```

I'm seeing a 50% speed increase on load on a i7, 16GB 5th Gen machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont see any improvement.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example

```
fn = 'my_file.xlsx'
parts = [dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(fn, i, **other_options) 
         for i in range(number_of_sheets)]
df = dd.from_delayed(parts, meta=parts[0].compute())
```

Assuming you provide the "other options" to extract the data (which is uniform across sheets) and you want to make a single master data-frame out of the set.

Note that I don't know the internals of the excel reader, so *how* parallel the reading/parsing part would be is uncertain, but subsequent computations once the data are in memory would definitely be.

Comment: Hi @mdurant, thanks for this answer! Did you mean to include brackets: `[parts = dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(fn, i, **other_options) for i in range(number_of_sheets)]`.

Comment: Aye, I suppose so

Comment: And I meant to use `parts = [dask....`, not my typo `[parts = dask...`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers based on multithreading (multiple threads in the same process, for example using Dask) don't work, because `pd.read_excel` permits only one operation in the same process. The code with Dask works, but it's not faster.

If you read multiple sheets concurrently using pandas, you need multiple processes, and for that we have the `multiprocessing` package.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count, current_process
import queue

xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sheet_names = xls.sheet_names

number_of_processes = cpu_count()
sheets_queue = Queue()
dataframes_queue = Queue()
processes = []

end = time.time()
print(f'Opening the XLS file took {(end - start):.2f} sec')

# fill input queue
for sheet in sheet_names:
    sheets_queue.put((local_file, sheet))


def read_sheets_from_queue(sheets_queue, dataframes_queue):
    have_more_data = True
    file_open = None
    while have_more_data:
        try:
            (file, sheet_name) = sheets_queue.get_nowait()
            if file != file_open:
                xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
                file_open = file
            print(f"\t{current_process().name} reading {sheet_name}")
            df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)
            dataframes_queue.put((sheet_name, df))
        except queue.Empty:
            have_more_data = False
            
    print(f"\tFinishing {current_process().name}")
    return True

    
# creating processes
for w in range(number_of_processes):
    p = Process(target=read_sheets_from_queue, args=(sheets_queue, dataframes_queue))
    processes.append(p)
    print(f"Starting process {w}")
    p.start()


# get the output
multi_dfs = {}
while len(multi_dfs) < len(sheet_names):
    (sheet_name, df) = dataframes_queue.get()
    multi_dfs[sheet_name] = df
```